# jQuery Как изменить элемент после его динамического добавления?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица, наполняемая динамически с помощью ajax.

> jQuery работает с элементами, которые были на странице на момент
>   инициализации кода. Если добавляются новые элементы - при помощи ajax'а
>   или функций типа append() - то события не затрагивают их.

Вопрос: какое событие нужно использовать для $('body').on(), чтобы выбрать нужные мне ячейки (по классу, по id, неважно) для последующей их обработки?

Если кратко о том, что именно хочу получить, то в каждой строке таблицы в одной из ячеек есть дата/время, а в другую ячейку этой же строки таблицы мне нужно воткнуть countdown-таймер, чтобы видеть оставшееся время (впоследствии уберу дату, останется только таймер).

Все найденные примеры используют событие click, в моем случае кликов никаких не предполагается.

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы добавили элементы от ответа ajax. можете сделать выборку. Пометив новые данные каким-то классом. а после того как сделаете нужные операции уберете класс.

Comment: в ответе ajax готовый html-код тела таблицы, я уже попробовал его распарсить, но как-то геморно... классы ячейкам я и так добавил в php-скрипте, куда обращается ajax, но, после $('#' + tableName).html(tableBody) элементы с этими классами недоступны.

Comment: А вы вставляете в html вашу таблицу?

Comment: да, по id tbody

Comment: <table id="extQuarTab" class="simpleTab">
<thead></thead>
<tbody id="qumh"></tbody>
</table>

Comment: Вы не поняли. Вы делаете вставку в нужное Вам месте при помощи `$('div').html(response.table)`?

Comment: нет, на странице есть элемент <table id="extQuarTab" class="simpleTab">, у него есть <tbody id="qumh">, и вот именно в него вставляется ответ аякса в виде набора строк <tr><td>...</td>...</tr>

Comment: метод вставки - да, html(data)

Comment: @Mortgoroth тогда рекомендую вставлять всё не `html`, а `append` в конец `tbody`

Comment: а будет разница? да, я могу переписать php-скрипт, чтобы он отдавал массив данных, которые будут формироваться в jQuery в нужные строки <tr></tr>, но после метода .append() разве будут доступны добавленные элементы?

Comment: @Mortgoroth вообще они должны быть доступны. А почему ты не можешь достучатся до них не понятно. Возможно метод вставки не тот. Скажи. а когда данные приходят и вставляются как они отображаются? в нормально виде?

Но я все же рекомендовал отдавать от php набор данных, а не `html`, а самим `js` уже добавлять. И плюс к этому ты можешь делать то что тебе нужно в процессе добавления элементов в `html`

Comment: не должны они быть доступны, я в вопросе об этом цитату написал, и это проверено неоднократно :) $('body').on('click', function(){...}) работает безотказно, но мне кликать не нужно. Данные приходят и вставляются абсолютно нормально. С набором данных попробую, но сомневаюсь, что ситуация изменится...

Comment: @Mortgoroth говориться именно о событиях, но не о простой выборке - $('selector'). Выбирать они должны в любом случае

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: какое событие нужно использовать для $('body').on(), чтобы выбрать нужные мне ячейки (по классу, по id, неважно) для последующей их обработки?

Если я правильно понял, просто запустить функцию после удачного ajax запроса.

```
success: ...,
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/